# using count(column) as x.count(column) mysql

Tags: mysql

here is my code i wish anybody can help me to solve my problem. my problem is in c.count and p.count lines. each of them does different works.

```
SELECT tablesite.name,
tablesite.family,
tablesite.phone_number,
job_list.job_name,
p.COUNT(action.service_provider_id) as positive,
n.COUNT(action.service_provider_id) as negative
FROM tablesite
INNER JOIN relation
on tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
INNER JOIN job_list
on relation.job_id=job_list.job_id 

LEFT JOIN action p
ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
AND action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment =''

LEFT JOIN action n
ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
AND action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment !=''


GROUP BY name, family,job_name, phone_number
```

i can not use p.count or n.count how can solve this problem.

> error: #1630 - FUNCTION p.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: how about `count(p. blah blah)`  that pattern, same for `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stab in the dark, but based on aliases going back to same table name `action` at least

```
SELECT tablesite.name,
tablesite.family,
tablesite.phone_number,
job_list.job_name,
COUNT(p.service_provider_id) as positive,
COUNT(n.service_provider_id) as negative
FROM tablesite
INNER JOIN relation
on tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
INNER JOIN job_list
on relation.job_id=job_list.job_id 

LEFT JOIN action p
ON tablesite.id_user=p.service_provider_id
AND p.vote !='' AND p.customer_comment =''

LEFT JOIN action n
ON tablesite.id_user=n.service_provider_id
AND n.vote !='' AND n.customer_comment !=''


GROUP BY name, family,job_name, phone_number
```

Comment: i think its true but why values of positive and negative is same?!

Comment: dang now I gotta do data and query fix too :) will gander

Comment: ok because the query is wishful thinking. A `left join` brings them all in. So the count is the same on a rowcount basis

Comment: you could involve a CASE WHEN block up top with positive and negative, only have one `left join` max

Comment: case when something 1 else 0 in a sum

Comment: I solved this question:  `FUNCTION p.COUNT does not exist`

Comment: ok i choose your answer but please answer my new question. do you want me create new question?

Comment: sure. Because it has nothing to do with this question. Also do a sqlfiddle with a few rows if necessary over there. People love it when you do that

Comment: stab in the dark means تیری در تاریکی in Persian lol. ok i call you for next question

Comment: I don't do RTL languages very well :) Still trying to learn Urdu

Comment: drew look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744966/repetitive-values-when-using-two-left-join-mysql try to learn persian ;)